# Python - Iterating dataframe using +/- oscillating values and create new column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, iterator

Need help labeling different states into new dataframe column based on the conditions of two oscillating values; Column X & Y.

Using Column Y, as the state interval.  State interval starts at 0 and ends at 0. Please note the values in Column Y will always stay in a positive or negative range. Each interval cycle will be in sequence order as all being +,-,+,- etc.

Labeling starts when Column Y values become positive going above 0 and stops at 0 before becoming negative; is the end of the cycle and would start the next range or cycle going into negative range.

There is a total of 6 patterns: A,B,C,D,E,F as cycle states. I'm trying to figure out the logic and how to add the label for each of the states into new dataframe column called state. Labeling happens for each cycle and starts over again with each new cycle state.

```
+-------+-------------+---------+  
| State |      X      |    Y    |  
+-------+-------------+---------+  
|   A   | from - to + |    +    |  
|   B   |      +      |    +    |  
|   C   |      -      |    +    |  
|   D   |      +      |    -    |  
|   E   |      -      |    -    |  
|   F   | from + to - |    -    |  
+-------+-------------+---------+
```

For State A & F, (Column X) has values goes from + to - or vice versa with crossover over 0. Values in Column Y will always stay in a positive or negative range.

States B,C,D,E have no crossing overs in (Column X). The following are example dataframe values and example new column with the resulting state.

---

```
+----+---------+---------+-------+  
|  # |    X    |    Y    | State |  
+----+---------+---------+-------+  
|  1 | -0.0034 |  0.0056 |   A   | Cycle 1 (+)  
|  2 | -0.0001 |  0.0070 |   A   |  
|  3 |  0.0019 |  0.0073 |   A   |  
|  4 |  0.0039 |  0.0075 |   A   |  
|    |         |         |       |  
|  5 |  0.0273 | -0.0037 |   D   | Cycle 2 (-)  
|  6 |  0.0237 | -0.0059 |   D   |  
|    |         |         |       |  
|  7 |  0.0047 |  0.0028 |   B   | Cycle 3 (+)  
|  8 |  0.0044 |  0.0020 |   B   |  
|    |         |         |       |  
|  9 | -0.0034 | -0.0006 |   E   | Cycle 4 (-)    
| 10 | -0.0045 | -0.0014 |   E   |  
|    |         |         |       |  
| 11 | -0.0021 |  0.0006 |   C   | Cycle 5 (+)  
| 12 | -0.0019 |  0.0007 |   C   |  
|    |         |         |       |  
| 13 |  0.0041 | -0.0054 |   F   | Cycle 6 (-)  
| 14 |  0.0017 | -0.0060 |   F   |  
| 15 | -0.0021 | -0.0059 |   F   |  
| 16 | -0.0023 | -0.0057 |   F   |  
+----+---------+---------+-------+  
Cycles will continue 7, 8, 9, 10, etc. in the time series
```

---

DataFrame with 12 cycles, similar to the sample above showcasing each of the patterns A,B,C,D,E,F twice in the results.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': [-0.0034, -0.0001, 0.0019, 0.0039, 0.0273, 0.0237, 0.0047, 0.0044, -0.0034, -0.0045, -0.0021, -0.0019, 0.0041, 0.0017, -0.0021, -0.0023, -0.0014, -0.0002, 0.0018, 0.0031, 0.0171, 0.0230, 0.0035, 0.0040, -0.0030, -0.0040, -0.0020, -0.0015, 0.0030, 0.0010, -0.0030, -0.0020, ],
    'y': [0.0056, 0.007, 0.0073, 0.0075, -0.0037, -0.0059, 0.0028, 0.002, -0.0006, -0.0014, 0.0006, 0.0007, -0.0054, -0.006, -0.0059, -0.0057, 0.0040, 0.005, 0.0065, 0.0070, -0.0022, -0.0045, 0.0020, 0.001, -0.0005, -0.0010, 0.0003, 0.0005, -0.0050, -0.005, -0.0060, -0.0040, ],
})
```

---

Next is example to start coding the iterating through the dataframe and need help building the logic, incorporate A & F states, going through each +/- cycle and guidance on how to iterate through Column Y looking for crossover values in Column X.

```
State = []

for i, row in df.iterrows():  #i: dataframe index; row: each row in series format  
    if row['X'] > 0 and row['Y'] > 0:  
        State.append('B')  
    elif row['X'] < 0 and row['Y'] > 0:  
        State.append('C')  
    elif row['X'] > 0 and row['Y'] < 0:  
        State.append('D')  
    elif row['X'] < 0 and row['Y'] < 0:  
        State.append('E')  
    else:  
        State.append('err')  

df['State'] = State  
print(df)
```

---

Again, the above code does not incorporate A & F states.

**Update**

Still need help, below is updated code with comments and will explain what's not working.

```
# Creating new column as + or - based on Column Y value
df['y_pos'] = np.where((df.y > 0), True, False)

# Creating new column to label the cycle as they are increasing order 1,2,3, etc.
df['cycle_n'] = (df.y_pos != df.y_pos.shift(1)).cumsum()

# returns dictionary whose keys and values are from DataFrames
# to be able to loop through the cycles
gb = df.groupby('cycle_n')
groups = dict(list(gb))

State = []

for name, group in gb:
    # Information to help compare our final results
    print("Group:" + str(name) )
    print("=====================")
    print("Min:" + str(group.min()) )
    print("Max:" + str(group.max()) )
    print("--- Group Data -----")
    print(group)
    print("--------------------")
    print("--- Column X Row Data -----")

    for index, row in group.iterrows(): # loop each row

        if row['y_pos'] == True: # Column Y is (+)

            print( row['x'] ) # row data value for Column X

        # trying to use min and max in each cycle to figure out
        # if there is a crossover 

        # ISSUE: min and max is holding data values for each of the
        # columns, not only Column X which maybe the reason why 
        # it's not working correctly

            if [ (group.min() <= 0) & (group.max() >= 0) ]:
                State.append('A')
            elif row['x'] >= 0:
                State.append('B')
            elif row['x'] < 0:
                State.append('C')
            else:  
                State.append('err')

        elif row['y_pos'] == False: # Column Y is (-)

            print( row['x'] )

        # ISSUE: again min and max is holding data values for each of the
        # columns, maybe the reason why it's not working correctly

            if [ (group.max() >= 0) & (group.min() <= 0) ]:
                State.append('F')
            elif row['x'] >= 0:
                State.append('D')
            elif row['x'] < 0:
                State.append('E')
            else:  
                State.append('err')
        else:
            print("err")

df['State'] = State  

# Combining y_pos & cycle_n to be printed out.
df['Label'] = 'Cycle ' + df.cycle_n.astype(str) + ' ' + df.y_pos.map({True: '(+)', False: '(-)'})

del df['y_pos']
del df['cycle_n']

print(df)
```

Issue with this code. It's only labeling State A & F now and mislabeling the other states as being A or F. The If statement using min and max returns true; really incorrect because it's holding values for all columns mins and max in the dictionary. For example,

```
print("Min:" + str(group.min()) )

Min:
x         -0.0034
y          0.0056
y_pos      1.0000
cycle_n    1.0000
dtype: float64
```

Don't know if this is the best way, just getting closer to it working correctly.

Comment: It would be easier for people to answer your question if you could provide a sample dataframe they can paste into their own code.

Comment: A few follow-up questions - what do you want to happen when you run out of letters (i.e. after `Z`)?  Also, is there a reason why you need to track what `df.X` is doing?  It looks like you could get away with just updating the label based on `df.Y`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do what you're trying to do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Define the cycles
df['y_pos'] = np.where((df.y > 0), True, False)
df['cycle_n'] = (df.y_pos != df.y_pos.shift(1)).cumsum()

# Function to classify states based on x and y
def classify_state(df):
    x_pos = df.x.max() >= 0
    x_neg = df.x.min() < 0
    y_pos = df.y_pos.any()

    if y_pos:
        if x_pos and x_neg:
            state = 'A'
        elif x_pos:
            state = 'B'
        else:
            state = 'C'
    else:
        if x_pos and x_neg:
            state = 'F'
        elif x_pos:
            state = 'D'
        else:
            state = 'E'

    df['state'] = state
    return df

# Apply that function over the cycles
df = df.groupby('cycle_n').apply(classify_state)

# Make the labels and clean up the temporary columns
df['label'] = 'Cycle ' + df.cycle_n.astype(str) + ' ' + df.y_pos.map({True: '(+)', False: '(-)'})
del df['cycle_n']
del df['y_pos']
```

A few points:

- As written, the logic works but is a little elaborate.  You could almost certainly do it in less lines, but I've left it in long form to make it clear what's going on.
- Values of `0` are considered to be positive in the code as written, but you can change this by altering `(df.iloc[[0, -1], 0] >= 0)`.

---

*Edit 1: Thanks for your thorough update to your question.  It's much clearer what you're looking for now, and I've changed the answer accordingly.*

*Edit 2: I've altered the code to take into account all `df.x` values within a cycle, not just the first and last ones.*

Comment: Definitely helpful.  There are a total of 6 patterns: A,B,C,D,E,F as cycle states.  Look at example state A & F.  Column X value goes from + to - or vice versa with crossover over 0.  Value in Column Y stays in positive or negative range.  This code continues labeling the alphabet and not incorporating only these 6 patterns.

Comment: @Life2Day I think I understand now and will update my code accordingly tonight.  Question - is the trend of `df.x` within a cycle always linear?

Comment: df.x is always oscillating with a trend going up or down, like df.y with values going above and below 0.

Comment: To help, based on your comments was able to get a little further along, but still having issues. Please read the Update above.

Comment: I looked at the changes to the question, but I'm not sure I see what's going wrong.

Comment: Please take another look at the latest update; was updating while your were reviewing.

Comment: I see - I think the issue is that you *did* want to take into account all the x values, not just the first and last.  Updated accordingly.

Comment: Well down, great work. Future update would be setting the cycle & state with err handling... when values are null.  again. thank you.